# Font linking broken on my PC

Tags: windows, fonts, unicode

I played a bit installing/uninstalling Google Noto fonts and suddenly symbols like ★ (U+2605) do not render in some applications (SQL Manager and Acrobat Reader for example) displaying "â˜…" instead (not a tofu block surprisingly...).

On another PC it's rendered, using SimSun font (which I tried to reinstall on my PC...), so I suspect I broke something in the font linking system...

But if I compare my HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink registry keys with those from a PC where the ★ is rendered correctly, there is no difference ...

Any idea of what might have gone wrong ?